# How to set workflow env variables depending on branch

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions

I currently have two GitHub actions workflow files that are pretty much identical, only one is configured to react to push/pull_requests on branch `master` the other on `production`.

The staging workflow starts like this:

```yaml
env:
  GCLOUD_PROJECT: my-project-stg
  VERCEL_TARGET: staging

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
```

The production workflow starts like:

```yaml
env:
  GCLOUD_PROJECT: my-project-prd
  VERCEL_TARGET: production

on:
  push:
    branches: [ production ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ production ]
```

The rest of the workflow files is the same, so this is clearly not very DRY.

I would like to have 1 single workflow file and somehow switch between two sets of variables based on the branch name. Is there a way to achieve this or am I maybe approach this from the wrong angle?

If it were possible to extend both workflow files on a shared base definition that would also solve it I guess.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is not possible to set workflow-level environment variables from a job. Each job runs in its own machine and setting an env variable there only affects all of the later steps in that job.

There are currently two ways to share data between jobs; either you create an artifact and use that, or you declare and set job outputs. The latter works for string values.

Here's an example:

```yaml
name: "Main"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - production
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - production

jobs:
  init:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      gcloud_project: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.gcloud_project }}
      phase: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.phase }}

    steps:
      - name: Cancel previous workflow
        uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.4.0
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}

      - name: Set variables
        id: setvars
        run: |
          if [[ "${{github.base_ref}}" == "master" || "${{github.ref}}" == "refs/heads/master" ]]; then
            echo "::set-output name=gcloud_project::my-project-dev"
            echo "::set-output name=phase::staging"
          fi

          if [[ "${{github.base_ref}}" == "production" || "${{github.ref}}" == "refs/heads/production" ]]; then
            echo "::set-output name=gcloud_project::my-project-prd"
            echo "::set-output name=phase::production"
          fi

  print:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: init
    steps:
      - name: Print
        run: echo "gcloud_project=${{needs.init.outputs.gcloud_project}}"
```

Comment: `set-output` is [deprecated now and we should use environment files instead](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)

Answer (score 20):

You can drop the global `env` statement, combine the event triggers to

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - production
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - production
```

and then add a first step that checks which branch the workflow is running on and set the environment there:

```yaml
      - name: Set environment for branch
        run: |
          if [[ $GITHUB_REF_NAME == 'master' ]]; then
              echo "GLCOUD_PROJECT=my-project-stg" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
              echo "VERCEL_TARGET=staging" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          else
              echo "GLCOUD_PROJECT=my-project-prd" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
              echo "VERCEL_TARGET=production" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          fi
```

Comment: Nice! I completely overlooked the workflow commands section. Awesome 

Comment: Unfortunately, set-env only works on the job level. You can not access these variables from other jobs. Therefore this approach is not a valid alternative for workflow level environment variables. Seems like set-output is something that can be (ab)used for this.

Comment: @ThijsKoerselman Hmmm, too bad :/ Feel free to accept your own answer, no hard feelings ;)

Comment: Wouldn’t this deploy any branch to production? Certainly not what you want

Comment: @chovy It triggers only on two branches, so if it's not `master`, it must be `production`, though the condition itself wouldn't check that.

Answer (score 4):

Things could have changed but for anyone still searching for an answer, there is a way to set a variabe visible for the entire workflow.

```
 jobs:
  weekday_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DAY_OF_WEEK: Mon
```

Then access by `jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env`

More info in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables)

Answer (score 4):

Create the respective environments on your repo settings, then use `environment` with condition based on branch name:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop

jobs:
  deploy:
    environment: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'production' || 'staging' }}
    ...
```

References:

Conditions: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example

Environment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment

Answer (score 2):

I found a way I think is neater in the GitHub docs. Assuming that there are only 2 branches i.e. dev & main:

```
env:
  MY_ENV_VAR: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'value_for_main_branch' || 'value_for_other_branches' }}
```

> In this example, we're using a ternary operator to set the value of
> the MY_ENV_VAR environment variable based on whether the GitHub
> reference is set to refs/heads/main or not. If it is, the variable is
> set to value_for_main_branch. Otherwise, it is set to
> value_for_other_branches. It is important to note that the first value
> after the && condition must be truthy otherwise the value after the ||
> will always be returned.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example

Answer (score -3):

There's now a better way of achieving this using reusable workflows:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows

Comment: Please explain how in particular reusable workflows will help with this scenario, rather than just linking to the reusable workflow documentation.